# Set style of each element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I have the following code to set the opacity of all elements not being hovered over to 0.5.

```
 const handleHover = function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("nav_link")) {
      const siblings = e.target.closest("nav").querySelectorAll(".nav_link");

      siblings.forEach((el) => {
        if (el !== e.target) el.style.opacity = this;
      });
     
    }
  };

$(".nav").on("mouseover", handleHover.bind(0.5));
$(".nav").on("mouseout", handleHover.bind(1));
```

My question is how can I write the forEach loop on the siblings using a jQuery method rather than using querySelectorAll?

Comment: Given how much you're _not_ using jQuery already, have you considered not using it at all?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use JavaScript or jQuery at all for this.

Using CSS, you can target all the `.nav_link` elements that are within a `nav` being hovered but are themselves, not hovered.

```css
.nav_link {
  transition: opacity .1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav:hover .nav_link:not(:hover) {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav_link">Link #1</li>
    <li class="nav_link">Link #2</li>
    <li class="nav_link">Link #3</li>
    <li class="nav_link">Link #4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

For completeness, here's a jQuery version

```js
// Delegated hover in / out event handler
$("nav").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".nav_link", e => {
  $(e.delegateTarget)     // start at "<nav>"
    .find(".nav_link")    // find all the links
    .not(e.target)        // except the hovered one
    .toggleClass("fade"); // toggle the "fade" class
});
```

```css
.nav_link { cursor: pointer; transition: opacity .1s; }
.fade { opacity: .5; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script><nav><ul><li class="nav_link">Link #1</li><li class="nav_link">Link #2</li><li class="nav_link">Link #3</li><li class="nav_link">Link #4</li></ul></nav>
```